# Why am I getting this error while attempting to mimic group concat in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Students` and another one called `Enrollment`. I want to get records of a particular student and which courses they are enrolled in.

I have worked with the MySQL function `GROUP_CONCAT` which is apparently not available in SQL Server, which is what I am working with right now. When I execute my stored procedure, I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Why am I getting this? I give the stored procedure a value of 1 when I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentDetails]
    @studentID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        s.studentId, s.firstName, s.lastName,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + e.courseId 
               FROM dbo.Enrollment as e
               FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS enrolledCourses
    FROM dbo.Students as s
    WHERE s.studentId = @studentID
END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have mismatched data types. `courseId` here is `INT`, so if you want to add a `,` before it, you have to convert it to `VARCHAR` first.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentDetails]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @studentID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT s.studentId, s.firstName, s.lastName,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), e.courseId)
              FROM dbo.Enrollment as e
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS enrolledCourses
    FROM dbo.Students as s
    WHERE s.studentId = @studentID
END
```

---

To further explain it, since you have a:

```
',' + e.courseId
```

SQL Server tries to convert both values into the data type with higher precedence. And since `INT` has a higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) than `VARCHAR`, it tries to convert `','` to `INT`, which then cause the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type
>   int.